# can findOneAndUpdate trigger schema post update/save?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, socket.io

I am stuck with socket io with problem emit the changes. Just wondering is there a way to trigger scheme.post update or save. at the moment scheme.post save doesn't work with **findOneAndUpdate**, please help out been stuck for hrs... any help much appreciated.

```
  project.schema.post('update', function (doc) {
    onSave(socket, doc);
  });
  project.schema.post('save', function (doc) {
    onSave(socket, doc);
  });
```

where does the udate

```
project.findOneAndUpdate(
    { 
      _id: req.body._id 
    },
    { $set: 
      { 'watchers' : req.body.watchers }
    },
    function(err, data) {
      return res.json(200, data)
    }
  );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That was an issue that is covered in some detail [here](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/964). I'll let you read through for the why but the solution was the maintainers added a special `post` hook for it:

```
 project.schema.post('findOneAndUpdate', function (doc) {
   onSave(socket, doc);
 });
```

NOTE: I am not sure if `doc` is provided though.

Comment: Thanks Jason i did try that with no luck, maybe i have to stick with save rather than findOneAndUpdate

Comment: @bluebill1049 Which version of MongooseJS are you using? It might be the version you are using doesn't include the fix.

Comment: "mongoose": "~3.8.8" (this is my version) Thanks Jason for helping i will vote it up anyhow, it probably have to do with my version.

Comment: @bluebill1049 Ah yes. I think it was only included in the 4.x release.